# Is it bad to run cron jobs to poll from a huge table of scheduled job records?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-design, architecture, cron

I've a table which a cron job would poll at every minute to send out messages to other services. The records in the table are essentially activities that are scheduled to run at a certain time. The cron job simply checks to see which of those activities are ready to be run and send a message of that activity through SQS to the other services.

When an activity is found to be ready to run by the cron job, that record will be marked as `done` after sending a message through SQS. There is an API which allows other services to check whether a scheduled activity has already been done. So keeping a history of those `done` records is needed.

My concern here, however, is whether a design like this is scalable in the long run. There are around 200k scheduled activities a day, or even more on some days. Since I'm keeping the records by marking them as `done` after they are completed, I'm worried that the table will eventually get very huge with ten over millions of rows and become an issue for the cron job to run as frequently.

Even with a properly indexed table, is my concern valid? Otherwise, what other alternatives can I design it if I had to somehow persist those scheduled activities for a cron or something to poll and check when they are ready to run?

I'm using Postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the number of rows that the cron job's query has to fetch stays constant and you can use an index, the size of the table won't matter.

Index scans are O(n) with respect to the number of rows scanned and O(log(n)) with respect to the table size. To be more specific, increasing the table size by a factor between 10 and 200 (smaller size of the index key leads to better fan-out) will make an index scan use one more block, and that block is normally cached.

If the table gets large, you might still want to consider partitioning, but mostly so that you can get rid of old data efficiently.

Comment: Does that mean, if I had my indexes planted on the fields which I'm going to put in my where clause, and if my `select` query returns 1000 records out of a table containing 100million records, I'm only affected by that 1000 records that I'm selecting? And thus, the computation is only `O(1000)`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

With the right index, the cron job should have no serious problem.  You can have a partial/filtered index, like

```
create index on jobs (id) where status <> 'done'.
```

To keep the size of the index small.  The query has to match the index where clause.

I used `(id)` just because an empty list is not allowed and so something has to be there.  Based on your comment, `schedule_dt` might be a better choice.  If you include all the columns you select, you can get an index-only scan.  But if you don't, it will still use the index, it just has to visit the table to fetch the columns for those specific rows.  I suspect the index only scan attempt won't be worth it to you as the pages you need probably won't be marked all visible, as modifications were made to neighboring tuples just one minute ago.

However, it does seem a bit odd to mark a job as done when it has only been scheduled, rather than being done.

> There is an API which allows other services to check whether a scheduled activity has already been done.

A table that increases in size without bound is likely to present management problems apart from the cron job. Surely the services aren't going to have to look back months in order to do this, are they?  Could you delete 'done' jobs after a few days?  What if a service tries to look up a job and rather than finding it 'done', it just doesn't find it at all?

I don't think the cron job is inherently a problem, but it would be cleaner not to have it.  Why doesn't whoever inserts the job just invoke SQS in real time?

Comment: In the index query `create index on jobs (id) where status <> 'done'`, is the `id` the field that is expected to be selected later in my query? If I had to select multiple fields such as `id`, `job_title`, etc, doesn't that mean I have to add something like `create index on jobs (id, job_title, schedule_dt) where status <> 'done'`?

Comment: A record will be only marked as `done` when it has been processed. Essentially, I've a field called `schedule_dt` which is a timestamp. When the cron runs and finds that `schedule_dt` is `>=` to current time, i'll process the job and mark the record as `done`. I could remove the `done` records but there is also a need to display a list of completed jobs. You can think of the frontend having to show a history of all the past scheduled jobs completed. It'd be great if there is a cleaner way to remove the completed records while still able to retrieve completed job records as history.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add info about what to put in the index column list. "It'd be great if there is a cleaner way to remove the completed records while still able to retrieve completed job records as history"  This is what partitioning is good for.  But how to partition would probably be driven by how far back you want to keep data viewable, not by considerations of your cron job.